# Apply selector to elements that have already been selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I feel like I am asking something really dumb but perhaps it's not my day. If I have a selected element already, e.g:

```
let tables = $('table');
```

But now I want to apply another selector like `.some-class` on top of those `tables`, but without creating a new jQuery object like this

```
$('table.some-class')
```

How would I do it?

Comment: May be like `$(tables+'.some-class');`

Comment: What about `find()`

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal `$('table').find('.some-class')` is _not_ the same than `$('table.some-class')`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to adding filter to variable selector.

```js
let tables = $('table');
tables = tables.filter('.some-class');
tables.css('color', 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>table</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="some-class">
  <tr>
    <td>table has .some-class</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

With the following code you would [find](https://api.jquery.com/find/) all elements with class `.some-class` under the elements with tag name `table`.

```
let tables = $('table').find('.some-class');
```

Of course, it is just for the example, otherwise you can simply do:

```
let tables = $('table .some-class');
```

In your question it is not clear if you want children elements or just [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) the elements. If you want the tables with a given class, you would do:

```
let tables = $('table').filter('.some-class');
```

Comment: I never mentioned children elements. I am trying to apply the selector on the original element.